# Any built in Captcha control from Microsoft to be used in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, nuget

Does microsoft provides any library for Captcha for MVC. I know there are third party ones but wondering if Microsoft has any one of its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuget packages typically have all the best development tools.

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/microsoft-web-helpers

ASP.NET Web Helpers Library - 1.15 with 33k+ has a strong following.

Comment: Nuget reports nothing for captchas unless I am doing something wrong in my search

Comment: I included a link directly to the Microsoft Web Helpers package which includes Captcha support. This link should help you get it working: 
http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/asp-net-web-pages-api-reference#Helpers

Please note it's actually called ReCaptcha.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nuget recaptcha package.

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/recaptcha

However, this isn't MVC specific.  You have to make a few modifications.  See:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/12/02/using-recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx